# Changing request parameter value in Struts2 interceptor

Tags: java, struts2, request, liferay-6, interceptor

Does anybody know if it is possible to change/remove request parameter values in a Struts2 interceptor?

The request parameter `Map` is an instance of `UnmodifiableMap` so it doesn't look like it can be manipulated with in the interceptor.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Liferay so `uParamsMap` will be an `UnmodifiableMap`

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) context.get(REQUEST);
    Map<String, String[]> uParamsMap = request.getParameterMap();
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with parameters? You can exclude them.

Comment: I'm have an interceptor for input validation and want to change the suspicious ones. I don't want to remove them completely because some of them might be legit

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Liferay

Comment: `invocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters()`.

Comment: I'll try setting values in `InvocationContext` parameters instead of `PortletRequest`. thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but what do you mean by "change the suspicious ones"? You can whitelist the parameters you allow; that should be sufficient.

Comment: I mean if the value of a parameter is suspicious. I'm using Antisamy to sanitize the values

Comment: The value of the parameter should be encoded/decoded, so the user can read it properly, that is done by the web container, what else you are doing is up to you, make sure the value is unmodified if you want to get actual value .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can try as this.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    Map<String,Object> parameters = (Map<String,Object>)context.get(ActionContext.PARAMETERS);

    Map<String, Object> parametersCopy = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametersCopy.putAll(parameters);
    parametersCopy.put("myParam", "changedValue");

    context.put(ActionContext.PARAMETERS, parametersCopy);

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've actually ended up solving it this way before I saw you answer so I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my code, but the solution above didn't work for me.

If you want to make changes to any parameters in the Interceptor before they get to the action class use this code:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {

    ValueStack stack=ai.getStack(); 
    Iterator it =  stack.getRoot().iterator();
    while( it.hasNext() )
    {
        Object objecto = it.next();
        //LoginUsuario is my action class
        if( objecto instanceof LoginUsuario )
        {
            LoginUsuario usuario = (LoginUsuario)objecto;
            usuario.setUsername( usuario.getUsername().toUpperCase() );
            usuario.setPassword( usuario.getPassword().toUpperCase() );
        }
    }
    return ai.invoke();
}
```