# Struts2 change form field using interceptor

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I am newbie in struts2.
In interceptor how can i change value of form field and then submitting it to database?
For example when user enters `firstName` value in form then when it submits i want to change `firstName` and then submit it to database.

Here is my interceptor's code

```
public class TestInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor implements Interceptor
{

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception
    {

        ValueStack stack = actionInvocation.getStack();

        Map<String, Object> params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
        Set<String> keys = params.keySet();

        System.out.println(keys + " " + stack.size());

        /*
         * for (String key : keys)
         * {
         * String[] value = (String[]) params.get(key);
         * System.out.println(value.length + " , " + value[0]);
         * }
         */
        Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        context.put("firstNames", "Changed");
        context.put("firstName", "Changed");
        stack.setParameter("firstName", "Changeds");
        stack.push(context);

        String result = actionInvocation.invoke();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing request parameter value in Struts2 interceptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076242/changing-request-parameter-value-in-struts2-interceptor)

Comment: It is not working in my case... Value is not updating

Comment: I got answer , in my code simply i need to change value in for each loop. no need to put any other context

Comment: was it a typo ? or you can add an answer if you fixed a real issue.

Comment: Why do you do this in interceptor? Action seems like a better place for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code simply you need to change value in the map. no need to put any other context.

```
Map<String, Object> params = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters();
params.put("firstName", "Changed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    Map<String,Object> parameters = (Map<String,Object>)context.get(ActionContext.PARAMETERS);

    Map<String, Object> parametersCopy = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametersCopy.putAll(parameters);
    parametersCopy.put("myParam", "changedValue");

    context.put(ActionContext.PARAMETERS, parametersCopy);

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.